# Fast Pollard Rho factorization in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, math, prime-factoring

I am trying to implement [Pollard Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) factorization method in Haskell.
Here is what I came to

```
func :: Int -> Int -> Int
func x n = mod ( x * x - 1) n

pollardStep :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
pollardStep i k n x y
      | d /= 1 && d /= n = d
      | i == k = pollardStep (i+1) (2*k) n x1 x1
      | otherwise = pollardStep (i+1) k n x1 y
      where d = gcd n $ abs $ y - x
            x1 = func x n

pollard_rho :: Int -> Int
pollard_rho n = pollardStep 1 2 n 2 2
```

This function if fine for small numbers like 8051.
But when I try to find factors for large numbers, for example, 1724114033281923457(I have checked, it is composite with factors 11363592254 and 1229739323) it takes forever(in that case function will never ends).
What am I doing wrong? I would be very appreciate to any help.

Comment: just switch `Int` to `Integer` everywhere - it's not the right answer but if I use your algorithm with just this changes and ask `pollard_rho 1724114033281923457` it gives me 1402015859 quite fast)

Comment: the reason is probably that `x*(x-1)` overflows when using `Int`

Comment: @Carsten That works!! brilliant answer) I spent 2 days to find out what is wrong!

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I move it into an answer then

Comment: It's instructive in cases like this to remove the type annotations entirely and see what Haskell infers for the types.

Comment: @chepner I am relativly new in Haskell, and I am not sure what do you mean. Can you apply an example code?

Comment: @ponkin just put `-- ` in front of lines of code like `func :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as far as I can tell the problem seems to be possible overflows you get when the numbers get too big for `Int` - in this case most likely in the `x * x - 1` part of `func` (`Int` has a `maxBound` of 9223372036854775807 on my system)

So the easiest option is just to switch to `Integer` everywhere as those are unbounded:

```
func :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
...

pollardStep :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer 
...

pollard_rho :: Integer -> Integer
...
```

this of course will make everything a bit slower though